# Iterating over the sum of values using a loop

Tags: arrays, matlab, for-loop, matrix

I have a row matrix as follows

```
a=[1 2 3];
```

The `for` loop has been implemented as follows

```
 for i=1:a(1,1:size(a,2))
    disp(i);
    disp("Hello");
end
```

Based on the values of the row matrix `Hello` has to be printed 6 times(i.e `1+2+3`) but it gets printed only once. How can I iterate along the row matrix and get `Hello` printed 6 times?

Answer (score 4):

```
a=[1 2 3];
for ii=1:sum(a)
    disp("Hello")
end
```

`1:a(1,1:size(a,2)) == 1:a(1,[1 2 3]) == 1:a(1,1) == 1:1 == 1` actually creates an array containing the number `1` (more specific: `a(1)`, as `1:[1 2 3]` will evaluate to `1:1`, discarding all elements further on in the vector). Given the number 6 you mention I take it you want the *sum* of all elements in `a` which is given by [`sum`](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cumsum.html).

Final word of caution: please refrain from using `i` and `j` as variable names, [as they also denote the imaginary unit](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14790740/5211833).

---

Reading your comment you probably need a nested loop, as the entries of `a` might not be monotonically increasing:

```
k = 1; % counter to show which iteration you're in
for ii = 1:numel(a) % for all elements of a do
    for jj = 1:a(ii) % do the following a(ii) times
        disp('Iteration %d', k)
        disp('Hello')
        k = k+1; % increase iteration count
    end
end
```

Note that both methods fail (obviously) when `a` does not contain strictly non-negative integer values.

Comment: not the sum I want to iterate it once, then twice and then thrice since I may need to implement such for loops in future. so how can I iterate in that manner?

Comment: Iterate once, then twice, then three times means you want to iterate on `sum(a)`. I don't see what the problem is in that case?

Comment: @KushanPeiris I think I solved your problem, see the edit, but this smells of an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/325771) so I think you're better of asking a new question with the actual code instead of an oversimplified example, so we can take a look whether the approach you're currently using is a good one (I suspect not, as this is a very contrived usage of loops).